# JQuery UI tabs and multiple Highcharts

Tags: jquery-ui, highcharts

I have troubles to bind multiple highcharts into jquery ui tabs. The first tab content will be loaded, but the other 2 tabs content will not displayed ...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Main</title>
<link href="/test/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/test/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/test/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
   $("#tabs").tabs();
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/test/tag_1.php">Tag</a></li>
        <li><a href="/test/monat_1.php">Monat</a></li>
        <li><a href="/test/jahr_1.php">Jahr</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"></div>
    <div id="tabs-3"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can call it [here](http://www.freelog.at/test/main.php).
Firebug say *Highcharts Error #16* --> [error description](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/16)

So, i know what the problem is, but i dont know how can i solve it.

Please, have you an hint for me ...

Best regards 
Andi

Comment: I advice to take look at this article: http://docs.highcharts.com/#faq$jquery-ui-tab

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i think this not the problem here. I have 3 unique php pages which are able to display different highcharts. These pages now i will included to one (jquer ui tabs page). Every time i change the tabs the new php file will be loaded (with highcharts.js) again. So, i must have a request, is highcharts currently loaded or not. But i dont know how can i handle this. Each .php file should be also work as stand-alone ;-)

Comment: How about show your code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href = "#tabs-1">...

<div id= "tabs-1"> aaaa
```

This solution works. Make sure your id's are same.
the li->a tag contains a '#' and id of the tab specified in the div tag.

solution to final code.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tag</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Monat</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Jahr</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">aaaa</div>
    <div id="tabs-2">bbbb</div>
    <div id="tabs-3">ccc</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, thats clear, but i want load the highcharts content from .php as you can see in my code above ...

Comment: give the highchart php contents in the <div> tags. Don't redirect the page. What you are actually doing is when the user click's on the tab he is being redirected to the php page.

Comment: i saw your code. when you change the tab you are loading the javascripts again which is causing the issue. please check the code for scripts in tab2 and tab3.

Comment: yes, this is the problem - how can i check if highchart.js is currently loaded and dont load it again?

Comment: load the scripts only on the page load. remove it from the php code. it will work fine.

Comment: this would be the simple solution :-) But for some reason the .php pages should also run as a "single" page. I think the easiest should be include at the .php files a request if highcharts.js is currently loaded or not. But i dont know how i can handle this ...

Comment: I have included this into the .php files: `<script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="/test/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>

<script>!window.Highcharts && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="/test/js/highcharts.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>

<script>!window.jQuery.ui && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="/test/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>`

Comment: try removing these scripts from the php page.

Comment: I have now removed highcharts.js and jquery.js from all 3 .php pages and included into the main.php. The first tab will be loaded correct, the other both tabs not. May have a look --> [here](http://www.freelog.at/test/main.php)

Answer (score 0):

sorry once again, I've not a working solution until yet. The first tab will displayed correct, the other two tabs will be not rendered.

I have excluded the highcharts.js and jquery.js libaries from .php files and call it only at the main.php see below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Main</title>
<link href="/test/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" ></script> 

<script>
$(function() {
   $("#tabs").tabs();
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#tabs .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
     position: absolute;
     top: -10000px;
     display: block !important;
}        

#tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
    width: 50%;
    height: 800px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/test/tag_2.php">Tag</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/test/monat_1.php">Monat</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/test/jahr_1.php">Jahr</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"></div>
    <div id="tabs-3"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

only at the first tab highcharts will be rendered correct. You can see it here --> [link](http://www.freelog.at/test/main.php)

here the head section of one not working .php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 

<title>Monatsübersicht</title>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(function () {
        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column'
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Monatsübersicht'                 
                },

                subtitle: {
                    text: '<span style="color: red">Monat: <?php echo $month; ?> Jahr: <?php echo $year; ?></span>'
                },

                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },

                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickInterval : 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                    labels: {
                            staggerLines: 2
                    },
                    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                        day: '%e.%b.'   
                    }
                },

                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'kWh'
                        },
                    min: 0
                },



                tooltip: {
                    shared: true,
                    crosshairs: true,
                    xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d'
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'Netz',
                    data: [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>],
                    pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
                    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day           
                },{
                    name: 'PV',
                    data: [<?php echo join($data2, ',') ?>],
                    pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
                    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
                }]
            });
        });
    });

    Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
        }
    });

</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that this is an old post now, but I recently had the same problem as you. My solution was to pass on a variable to the external php files to name the renderTo container. Like this:

Main page:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="/test/tag_2.php?id=1">Tag</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/test/monat_1.php?id=2">Monat</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/test/jahr_1.php?id=3">Jahr</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1"></div>
<div id="tabs-2"></div>
<div id="tabs-3"></div>
```

Then give your "renderTo: container these ID numbers like this:

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>',
                type: 'column'
            },
```

It worked for me, so I hope you can use it to solve your problems.

/Carl